# jQuery: Show a zoom button on hover over the image and another layer which is black but faded

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve simple effects here and there. Please look this code and tell me if I can achieve the same thing with a better approach.

I am trying to show a zoom button when I hover over the image and another layer which is black but faded to degree to get this common fade effect.

First that's my html sample:

```
<a href="<LARGE_IMAGE_URL" class="zoom(for fancybox)">
    <img src="IMAGE_SMALL_SOURCE.jpg" />
    <div class="zoom-overlay"></div>
    <div class="zoom-black"></div>
</a>
```

This is the jQuery I wrote..

```
// click to zoom button
$(".zoom-overlay").css({display: "none"});
$(".zoom-black").css({display: "none"});
$(".slidingposts .image").hover(function(){
    $(this).children("a").children(".zoom-black").show();
    $(this).children("a").children(".zoom-black").fadeTo(1, 0.40);
    $(this).children("a").children(".zoom-overlay").fadeIn(500);
},function(){
    $(this).children("a").children(".zoom-black").hide();
    $(this).children("a").children(".zoom-overlay").fadeOut(300);
});

$(".slidingposts .image").click(function(){
    $(".zoom-black:visible").hide();
    $(".zoom-overlay:visible").hide();
});
```

I do not know if I can achieve same results with better code. I feel it could be improved any guidance?

It seems to do what I want. First I want the black overlay to show then fade it a bit, then the main overlay with button appears (I styled that already) .. and whenmouse out i just hide the overlays and thats it.

I also put a code onclick to hide the visible overlays because it interfere with the fancybox wrap.

Any suggestions?

Comment: prefer `.hide()` to `.css({display:'none'})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not messing with your HTML, since I don't really know the details of the design there.  Instead, I'm optimizing your jquery here.  It's should be pretty much equivalent, just a little slimmer.

```
// click to zoom button
$(".zoom-overlay, .zoom-black").css({display: "none"});

$(".slidingposts .image a").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".zoom-black").fadeTo(1, 400);
    $(this).children(".zoom-overlay").fadeIn(500);
},function(){
    $(this).children(".zoom-black").hide();
    $(this).children(".zoom-overlay").fadeOut(300);
});

$(".slidingposts .image").click(function(){
    $(".zoom-black:visible, .zoom-overlay:visible").hide();
});
```

I should explain a little.  Since all the targets were the anchors, I added them to the end of the selector so all those children('a') could be removed.  Then I consolidated some other selectors because you wanted to perform the same action on the targets.

Comment: Can you or someone explain to me why css display: none is better approach than hide? It was recommended many times.. i want to know why

Comment: You know, I've not given that a lot of thought, honestly.  hide() does have a lot of options, like duration, easing, callbacks... css() just sets the given css property.  I imagine it's a slightly more direct route, but I tend to just use hide() because it's easy to read and understand my intention of hiding something.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly is in the class definitions, the two `div` elements in the anchor (`a href`) are probably unnecessary. You can apply classes directly to  anchor and image elements. Also, the `animate` method in jQuery can accept certain CSS properties, making the class definitions unnecessary as well. Finally, you can store the result of your queries to reuse them later, or (better yet) chain the jQuery functions. Repeatedly querying for the same element is not ideal.